# Sort JSON based on custom sort order array

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I want to sort the below json response based on an array.

```
{
    "expanded": {
        "developer": {
            "numFound": 1,
            "start": 0,
            "maxScore": 0.13050619,
            "docs": [
                {
                    "title": "developer"
                }
            ]
        },
        "shop": {
            "numFound": 1,
            "start": 0,
            "maxScore": 1.1272022,
            "docs": [
                {
                    "title": "shop"
                }
            ]
        },
        "support": {
            "numFound": 84,
            "start": 0,
            "maxScore": 1.3669837,
            "docs": [
                {
                    "title": "support"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to sort based on the below sort array (in same order as below).

```
[ 'shop', 'support', 'developer']
```

Is there a way to sort this json based on some custom value?

Comment: Filter them to an array, then sorting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sort json, but you can create an array of objects and sort that:

```js
let foo = {"expanded": {"developer": {"numFound": 1,"start": 0,"maxScore": 0.13050619,"docs": [{"title": "developer"}]},"shop": {"numFound": 1,"start": 0,"maxScore": 1.1272022,"docs": [{"title": "shop"}]},"support": {"numFound": 84,"start": 0,"maxScore": 1.3669837,"docs": [{"title": "support"}]}}};

let orderArr = ['shop', 'support', 'developer'];

let res = Object.keys(foo.expanded)
    .map(a => ({[a] : foo.expanded[a]}))
    .sort((a,b) => (orderArr.indexOf(Object.keys(a)[0]) + 1) - (orderArr.indexOf(Object.keys(b)[0]) + 1));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no need to sort since the order for the properties is explicitly defined.  Instead, just place the required objects into an array:

```
let ordered = ['shop', 'support', 'developer'].map(property => {
  return {[property]: foo.expanded[property]};
});
```